# SELECT retornando dados que não foram vistos por determinado usuario

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select

Estou com dificuldades para montar uma *Query*

Tenho 2 tabelas:

- `video_visualizacoes` com os campos `visualizacao_id, video_id, conta_id` (Esse campo se refere ao usuário que visualizou o vídeo)".
- `videos` com os campos `video_id, video_titulo e conta_id` (Esse campo se refere ao `uploader` do video)"

Preciso uma *Query* que retorne todos os vídeos que ainda não foram vistos por determinado usuário.

Comment: Pode postar o que já tentou fazer até agora?

Comment: Seria interessante colocar um exemplo das tabelas, utilize esta ferramenta: http://lorefnon.me/plain-text-table/

Answer (score 3):

Da seguinte maneira você conseguirá

```
select v.* from videos v
where v.video_id not in (select t.video_id video_visualizacoes t where t.conta_id=v.conta_id)
and v.conta_id= id
```

Comment: Dois where na mesma consulta? não seria um `and` ali no final.

Comment: Desculpe, editarei o post, na verdade seria um and

Comment: O @LeandroLUK percebeu a gafe e editou

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou algo do tipo:

```
SELECT videos.video_id
FROM videos 
JOIN video_visualizacoes ON videos.conta_id <> video_visualizacoes.conta_id 
ORDER BY videos.video_id DESC
```